# Error computing quantiles on large RasterStack

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, quantile, netcdf4

I want to get quantiles of each cell across layers on a stacked set of RasterLayers on R.

My RasterStack looks like this

> dimensions : 721, 1440, 1038240, 18628  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)

I run the following line to get a layer whose values are 25th and 75th percentiles for each cell

```
qtiles <- raster::calc(RasterStack, fun=function(x){quantile(x, probs = c(0.25,0.75), na.rm=TRUE)})
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in R_nc4_open: NETCDF: HDF error
Error in ncdf4::nc_open(x@file@name, suppress_dimvals = TRUE) :
  Error in nc_open trying to open file U:path/file1.nc (return_on_error= FALSE )
```

I suspect it's because of the number of layers since when I try it on a subset of netcdf files, it works fine, and I also have no problems in opening file1.nc separately.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of your files is corrupted. You can find it by looping over all your files, opening it and doing something with it (some action that will actually read the cell values like `x * 1`)

You can also try the more efficient

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(vector of filenames)
q <- quantile(r, probs = c(0.25,0.75), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! With terra it works smoothly, however, when I compute quantiles certain quantiles (e.g. `c(0.05,0.1)` ), I get a full layer of 0s, which I inspected the data and cannot be the case (for e.g. `c(0.95)`  it works well). Do you have any ideas?